# pytest object equality with __eq__ overriden

Tags: python, pytest

I am using peewee for a project and I ran into an issue when it came to test. I want to check if a function has been called with a specific parameter which is a peewee Expression. The issue here is that peewee.Expression overrides the __eq__ operator: https://github.com/coleifer/peewee/blob/master/peewee.py#L379

So, now whatever is put on the right side of the `==` expression will return a new expression and evaluated as a True by pytest.

Is there something in the pytest library which test object equality by attributes instead of using the `==` operator?

Comment: You have numerous options - mock the `Expression`, compare the `__dict__`s, explicitly compare type and attribute values, invert the test use your own comparator object implementing `__eq__` appropriately, ...

Comment: You can also check the lhs and rhs of the expression object.

Comment: Explicitly comparing type and attributes as suggested by @jonrsharpe would be the way to go, possibly implementing a fixture to do that work for you.

Comment: thx @jonrsharpe the comparison on the `__dict__` was a good solution

Answer (score 0):

For those who are interested I found a solution to perform that easily

```
def _extract_call_dict(name, args, kwargs=None):
    """Checks if the current element has an overriden __eq__ method"""
    if kwargs is None:
        # mock._Call is a superclass of Tuple and can have 
        # 2 or 3 elements. So, I unpack them and ajust my args accordingly
        args, kwargs = name, args

    # This check can be improved, my use case is pretty simple,
    # so I only check types
    has_eq_overriden = lambda obj: (isinstance(obj, peewee.Model) or
                                    isinstance(obj, peewee.Expression))

    # Replace the object by its dict representation if boolean is True
    get_dict = lambda obj: obj.__dict__ if has_eq_overriden(obj) else obj

    # apply this treatment for every elements from _Call
    args = [get_dict(arg) for arg in args]
    kwargs = {key: get_dict(value) for key, value in kwargs.items()}

    # return a new instance
    return mock.call(args, kwargs)

class _Call(mock._Call):
"""Override the _Call class from mock"""

    def __eq__(self, other):
        """This will be use every time you try to compare 
           mock.call statements
        """
        self_replacement = _extract_call_dict(*self)

        if isinstance(other, mock._Call):
            other = _extract_call_dict(*other)

        return super(_Call, self_replacement).__eq__(other)

# Override mock.call to be compliant with peewee __eq__ override
unittest.mock._Call = test.utils._Call
```